# Can I store a request token and if not, how can I obtain one without repeating the authorization procedure?

Tags: c#, api, twitter, dotnetopenauth

I'm attempting to use the Twitter API with the DotNetOpenAuth library.

I have a working sample that posts tweets, but unfortunately, it forces the user to authorize the application each time it starts up.

According to the Twitter docs, I can avoid that by storing the access token. I have done this.

My question is, how can I get DotNetOpenAuth to get a new request token and use an existing access token *without* forcing the user to authorize the app again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - I'm not sure if it's optimal or not, but it works.

I simply store the `access` and `access_secret` tokens and dump them back into the token manager when the application is started again.

Comment: That is exactly what you're supposed to do -- probably.  You're not supposed to use the `InMemoryTokenManager` -- that's for samples only.  You're supposed to write your own token manager that dumps tokens into a database and retrieves them on demand.  It sounds like you're doing (roughly) that.

Comment: @Andrew: Wait... you're the guy that wrote the library right? Thanks so much for writing it! I wrote my own token manager as you mentioned and that seems to be working fine now. Wonderful library, btw.